# How do you determine the audio latency (AudioTrack) on Android?

Tags: java, android, audio, audiotrack

I have an app in which I use an `AudioTrack` in streaming mode to play dynamically generated audio.  The app doesn't have to respond instantaneously to inputs, so the latency issues don't bother me for that side of the program.

The problem is that I have an animation that needs to be as precisely 'in-sync' as possible with the audio and it seems that different devices have different amounts of time between when the `AudioTrack` stops blocking the `write()` call and asks for more data, and when that audio is played from the speaker.

My current solution gets me most of the way there -- I count the number of frames I've passed in to the `AudioTrack` so far, and compare it to `getPlaybackHeadPosition()`.  It looks basically like:

```
long currentTimeInFrames = 0;
while(playingAudio) {
  currentTimeInFrames += numberOfFramesToWrite;
  long delayInFrames = (currentTimeInFrames - audioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition());
  audioTrack.write(frameBuffer,0,sampleSize);
  doAnimationAfterDelay(delayInFrames);
}
```

However, there's still some latency that `getPlaybackHeadPosition()` doesn't seem to account for that varies by device.

Is there a way to poll the system for the latency of the AudioTrack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider driver's latency. There's hidden function AudioManager.getOutputLatency(int) to get this.

Call it like this:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
try{
   Method m = am.getClass().getMethod("getOutputLatency", int.class);
   latency = (Integer)m.invoke(am, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

I get about 45 - 50 ms on different devices.
Use the result in your calculations.

Comment: Note, that on some devices throws `MethodNotFoundException`

Comment: There is another hidden method `AudioTrack.getLatency` that is more accurate, since it lives on the AudioTrack instance and thus can account for hardware/route-specific latency as well. It can be invoked in a similar fashion via reflection: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/audio-video-synchronization.html#section1-2

Answer (score 5):

API level 19 adds a method in `AudioTrack` called  [getTimeStamp()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getTimestamp(android.media.AudioTimestamp)). From the documentation:

> Poll for a timestamp on demand.
>
> If you need to track timestamps during initial warmup or after a routing or mode change, you should request a new timestamp periodically until the reported timestamps show that the frame position is advancing, or until it becomes clear that timestamps are unavailable for this route.

You specify an [AudioTimestamp](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTimestamp.html) object as the function's parameter and it will fill in the most recently "presented" frame position along with its "estimated" timestamp in nanoseconds. The nanosecond value corresponds to the millisecond value returned by [SystemClock.uptimeMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis()).

You can then determine the latency by figuring out when you wrote that particular frame to `AudioTrack` vs. when `getTimestamp()` thinks it actually presented. I have found this method to be more accurate than the other methods mentioned above.

You have to be careful though. The documentation says `getTimeStamp()` is not supported on all platforms or all routes. You can determine if the call was successful by checking the `boolean` return value. I have found with the devices I have tested that the function returns false until audio begins presenting, and then subsequent calls return true. I have only tested with `AudioTrack` in `STREAM_MUSIC` mode. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Can you explain more about how you actually calculate the latency? Do you store a list of (frame,time) pairs when writing into the AudioTrack and then compare them against getTimestamp later? How often do you call getTimestamp?

Comment: @tmm1 -- (sorry for not responding sooner.) I have a latency calculation I am using in my app. However, I'm not convinced that it is correct, so I haven't posted it yet. I want to do some more research and maybe tweak my solution. I'll update my answer when I do.

Comment: getTimeStamp(1) return value corresponds to System.nanoTime(), not SystemClock.uptimeMillis(). See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTimestamp

Answer (score -1):

You should take into account the buffersize you passed along into the AudioTrack creation.

```
final int minBufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(Application.PLAYRATE,
AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

out=new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, Application.PLAYRATE, 
AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufSize, 
AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

extraLatencyFrames = minBufSize/4;
```

Comment: Hmm.. now that I think again of it. It would be weird if that minimum buffer size was not accounted for in the head position.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, this is the key. First you need to extend the Audiotrack class, and then use the getNativeFrameCount to have an approximation on the latency involved in the native side of things.

```
class MyAudioTrack extends AudioTrack
{
    public MyAudioTrack(int streamType, int sampleRateInHz, int channelConfig,
            int audioFormat, int bufferSizeInBytes, int mode)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        super(streamType, sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat,
                bufferSizeInBytes, mode);
        System.out.println("Native framecount "+getNativeFrameCount());
    }   
    public int getFrameCount()
    {
        return getNativeFrameCount();
    }
}
```