# getOutputLatency () Android audio

Tags: android, audio, latency

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802659/how-do-you-determine-the-audio-latency-audiotrack-on-android) while looking for a way to measure output latency on an Android device

i tried that answer and it gave me 50 ms delay. is there really a hidden method called `getOutputLatency()` ?

I looked around and i could not found it anywhere but in that thread.

Comment: [Yes, there is](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/base/tree/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java?h=aosp-new/master) (scroll down to the bottom). But I don't know when it was added, so it may not exist on some Android versions (and, not being part of the official API, it could be removed without warning in some future version). Note that you'll probably get a static latency value from this function, i.e. an estimate made by the developers of what the average latency will be.

Comment: exactly. it worked on some devices and didn't on others. i got a static result which is not what i want. i want to see the variation of this latency. i also found Raph levien's application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levien.audiobuffersize,  but it gave me way far different result.i dont know which one to use.

Comment: Hanaa, So what did you end up with? Did you successfully find the right way of doing this?